# Euro Currency formatting

Tags: coldfusion

I am using

```
LSEuroCurrencyFormat(2500)
```

to format the price. the output is like

```
2.500,00 €
```

but I want to display the price like

```
 2.500,- €
```

how may I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
replace(LSEuroCurrencyFormat(2500),",00",",-")
```